# Detecting state mutation in Python

Tags: python, immutability

Is there any way to detect state mutation in Python? I'm working on some software where all mutated state must be saved to an external database, and I'd like to write an automated test to detect state which has not been persisted.

More background on the problem: my software has a set of "worker" processes, and these processes can be restarted at any time. So it is necessary for a worker process to recover its state from the database if it is restarted.

My concern is that there may be state mutation which is not persisted to the database (and therefore not recovered when the worker is restarted). I'm wondering if there is any way to automatically defect this. I'd be happy to detect *all* state mutation and exclude that which I know is persisted to the database.

Comment: It would make sense to use an ORM library like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for this. An ORM library will keep track of which database-mapped objects have been mutated. Is this something you've considered and decided against?

Comment: Just for the record, there was no need to [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70366024/6045800). You could edit your original question and it could get reopened if enough details were added

Answer (score 0):

There is no "built-in" state change management as far as I know in Python. But something that will probably help you is the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). To quote the beginning of the article :

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, named the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.

A typical solution is to have an [enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) of possible states. When an object changes state, you update the a state attribute through an enumeration and notify the observers.

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class State(Enum):
    START = auto()
    ACTION = auto()
    END = auto()

class MyObject: # observable
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.observers = []
        self.conn = conn
        self.state = State.START
  
    def subscribe(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def _notify(self):
        for o in observers:
            o.update()

    def do_action(self, expr):
        conn.execute(expr) # some SQL executed here
        self.state = State.ACTION # update state
        self._notify() # notify observers
    
    def kill_conn(self):
        conn.cancel() 
        self.state = State.END
        self._notify()

class MyLogger: # observer
    def __init__(self, my_object):
        self.my_object = my_object
        self.my_object.subscribe(self)

    def update(self):
        match self.my_object.state: # Python 3.10 structural pat matching
            case State.START: pass # your code here
            case State.ACTION: pass # your code here
            case State.END: pass # write current object to log file?
            case _: pass # 'default' behavior is catching the rest fails
```